# Bluetooth sockets using python

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth

I was wondering, is there any way to send a socket message to a connected bluetooth device using python?

I already tried this:

```
import socket 
import bluetooth

bd_addr = "Device mac adress"
port = 1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)

sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
sock.send("hello!!")
sock.close()
```

Comment: do you have a server socket on the receiving end ?

Comment: Im trying to send it to a bluetooth device but i dont know if its possible?

Comment: It is possible as documented at: https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/. However, it is very dependent on the hardware you are running the Python on and what Bluetooth services are available on the device you are connecting to. Can you update the question with some more information please.